# cant send to gmail. Remote host said: 421 4.7.0 Senders Guidelines

Tags: smtp, gmail

I have a SMTP account by hostgator. It has been working OK for a few years. in the last week all emails sent to gmail accounts are bounced with the following message:

> Could not deliver message to the following recipient(s): Failed
>
> Recipient: USERNAME@gmail.com Reason: Remote host said: 421 4.7.0
>
> Senders Guidelines.  rx5si6064874pab.151 - gsmtp    -- The header and
>
> top 20 lines of the message follows -- Received: from COMPUTERNAME
>
> (cpe-184-152-65-14.nyc.res.rr.com  [184.152.65.14]) by
>
> srv1.MYDOMAIN.com with SMTP;    Wed, 30 Dec 2015 20:20:02 +0000
>
> MIME-Version: 1.0 From: info@MYDOMAIN.com To:
>
> =?utf-8?Q?=D7=92=D7=9C=D7=99=D7=A7_=D7=95=D7=95=D7=90=D7=9C=D7=A3?=
>      Cc: info@MYDOMAIN.com Date: 30 Dec 2015 15:20:00
>
> -0500 Subject: Hello Content-Type: multipart/alternative;  boundary=--
>   boundary_24_202cb606-d866-4f0c-8099-34ebd832de7f

emails sent to other domains (aol,yahoo,etc...) arrive safely. the issue is only to gmail.

i couldnt find much info online. most posts refer to a bulk sending message. but these emails are not bulk. nor is there any reference to bulk in the error response

in the smtp logs from hostgator/smartermail i dont find anything interesting. in fact it seems to be all-ok.

heres a sample

> 01:46:33 [99.99.99.99][57058974] rsp: 220 srv1.MYDOMAIN.com
>
> 01:46:33 [99.99.99.99][57058974] connected at 1/4/2016 1:46:33 AM
>
> 01:46:33 [99.99.99.99][57058974] cmd: EHLO COMPUTERNAME
>
> 01:46:33 [99.99.99.99][57058974] rsp: 250-srv1.MYDOMAIN.com Hello
>   [99.99.99.99] 250-SIZE 250-AUTH LOGIN CRAM-MD5 250 OK
>
> 01:46:33 [99.99.99.99][57058974] cmd: AUTH login
>   aW5mb0BqdWRhaWNhcdhcmUuY29t
>
> 01:46:33 [99.99.99.99][57058974] rsp: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
>
> 01:46:33 [99.99.99.99][57058974] rsp: 235 Authentication successful
>
> 01:46:33 [99.99.99.99][57058974] Authenticated as info@MYDOMAIN.com
>
> 01:46:33 [99.99.99.99][57058974] cmd: MAIL FROM:
>
> 01:46:33 [99.99.99.99][57058974] rsp: 250 OK 
>   Sender ok
>
> 01:46:33 [99.99.99.99][57058974] cmd: RCPT TO:
>
> 01:46:33 [99.99.99.99][57058974] rsp: 250 OK 
>   Recipient ok
>
> 01:46:33 [99.99.99.99][57058974] cmd: RCPT TO:
>
> 01:46:33 [99.99.99.99][57058974] rsp: 250 OK 
>   Recipient ok
>
> 01:46:33 [99.99.99.99][57058974] cmd: DATA
>
> 01:46:33 [99.99.99.99][57058974] rsp: 354 Start mail input; end with
>   .
>
> 01:46:34 [99.99.99.99][57058974] rsp: 250 OK
>
> 01:46:34 [99.99.99.99][57058974] Data transfer succeeded, writing mail
>   to 97641527.eml
>
> 01:47:39 [99.99.99.99][57058974] cmd: QUIT
>
> 01:47:39 [99.99.99.99][57058974] rsp: 221 Service closing transmission
>   channel
>
> 01:47:39 [99.99.99.99][57058974] disconnected at 1/4/2016 1:47:39 AM

the official google page here https://support.google.com/a/answer/3726730?hl=en has several error descriptions. but none match what i am getting "Senders Guidelines"

what can i do about this? where can i look? any links/leads/pointers?

thanks!

Comment: https://support.google.com/a/answer/3726730?hl=en

Comment: hi. thank you. i forgot to note that i already checked that. but the error messages dont match. the closest match is about bulk guidelines, but  a)i am not sending bulk, and   b) the messages are not identical

Comment: The beginning of the message is cut off by your local mail system. The complete message is: "Our system has detected an unusual rate of unsolicited mail originating from your IP address. To protect our users from spam, mail sent from your IP address has been temporarily blocked. Review our Bulk Senders Guidelines."

Comment: hi. thanks. who is cutting off the message? hostgator? smartermail? is there a setting anywhere where i can set to get complete messages?

Comment: @MichaelHampton can you please elaborate how we can get the full error messages in the log?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your domain is hosted on the Shared environment. In this case, you should contact the service provider i.e. Hostgator. Generally, such errors occur when Google detects some unusual rate of the mail to Gmail from a mail server IP address.

It may be possible that the other domains hosted on the same server have sent the unsolicited mails to Gmail. Here, the tech guy from HostGator can investigate the actual account who sends the mail.